# Can jquery be used to rearrange visual source order of HTML when building a mobile first layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css, susy-compass

I was trying to build a mobile first layout with Susy grid system, where the main content had three columns, left aside, seciton.class"maincontent", and right aside.  The middle column of "maincontent"would be what I want to appear first in mobile layout, while the smaller asides would appear after the maincontent.  When using Susy it seems like I have to structure the markup, so that the main content comes after the left aside if I want everything to look correct on the Desktop layout.  Can something like Jquery be used so that at a certain breakpoint, it is used to create a visual source order change and allow the main content to be inserted in between the two asides on a Desktop layout? Or am I stuck having to have a mobile first layout where the left aside appears before the main content?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pull to offset the columns contrary to the source order:

```
// pull(<$columns> [, <$context>, <$from>, <$style>])
.box { @include pull(2); }
```

[Pull @ Susy Doc](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/susyone/#pull)